# Redirect output of systemd service to Ubuntu Boot Screen (20.04)

Tags: boot, gnome, shutdown, desktop-environments

I have a systemd service that performs sync between local disk and Cloud Storage during shutdown. Something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Syncing with MEGA cloud storage v56
After=network-online.target

[Service]
...
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/usr/local/sbin/auto-sync.sh
RemainAfterExit=true
TimeoutStopSec=0
...
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now, I've upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and during Ubuntu shutdown\boot see only black screen with 'Ubuntu' inscription in the bottom. I don't have any vendor image. And I'm wondering If I can redirect output of my auto-sync.sh script to Ubuntu shutdown screen.

The best option here would be to arrange some square in the center of the screen and print there white text just like any console/terminal does. So, I have several questions:

1. Is something like that possible at all ?
2. Could it be done just with Bash and some Ubuntu\Gnome configuration ?
3. May be I have to write a separate application ?

Any thoughts\idea\guidelines are welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is discussed at length in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/560167/how-can-i-write-to-console-during-shutdown) site:

> For a systemd service you need a `TTYPath=/dev/console` and a
> `StandardOutput=tty` in the .INI file to change this,
> `StandardInput=tty` if you want to read (but you do not) as well as
> write. Witness systemd's pre-supplied `debug-shell.service`.

There is a lot more in the link as well as additional sources linked in.

Comment: It doesn't help cause Ubuntu boot screen hides /dev/console. When boot screen is active - I can't see a console,with that option specified it appears for a couple of seconds after boot screen.